# when i click on the edit text which is the row 1 of tablet layout ,set text happens for the last row of the table

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

When ever i click on the any edittexts on any row  - a dialog box shows up

Then onClick of the dialog setText  happen for that clicked edittext.

But Text is always set to the  edittext of last row of the tablet layout

Please help

Below is the Code :

private void displayWorkOrderSearch() {

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mExtendedSearchCollectionList.size(); i++) {

        final ExtendedSearchCollection extendedSearchCollectionObj = mExtendedSearchCollectionList.get(i);

        final TableRow fTableRow = new TableRow(WorkOrderSearchActivity.this);
        if (extendedSearchCollectionObj.getMODULENAME().equalsIgnoreCase("WORKORDER") && extendedSearchCollectionObj.getSCREENNAME().equalsIgnoreCase("WO_SEARCH")) {

            Log.e("WorkOrderSearch", "  testing label" + extendedSearchCollectionObj.getUILABEL());

            TextView fLabelView = CommonElements.getCreateTextView(context);
            fLabelView.setText(extendedSearchCollectionObj.getUILABEL());


            switch (extendedSearchCollectionObj.getUIFIELDTYPE()) {
            case "ID":

                fEditTextID = CommonElements.getCreateEditText(WorkOrderSearchActivity.this, extendedSearchCollectionObj.getUIFIELDTYPE());

                fEditTextID.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        makeServiceCalls(extendedSearchCollectionObj.getDDCOLLECTIONNAME(), extendedSearchCollectionObj.getDDFIELDNAME(), extendedSearchCollectionObj.getDDTABNAME());
                    }
                });
                fTableRow.addView(fLabelView);
                fTableRow.addView(fEditTextID);
                fTableLayout.addView(fTableRow);


                break;
            case "TF":
                EditText fEditTextTF = CommonElements.getCreateEditText(WorkOrderSearchActivity.this, extendedSearchCollectionObj.getUIFIELDTYPE());

                fEditTextTF.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    }
                });

                fTableRow.addView(fLabelView);
                fTableRow.addView(fEditTextTF);
                fTableLayout.addView(fTableRow);

                break;

            case "DF":
                EditText fEditTextDF = CommonElements.getCreateEditText(WorkOrderSearchActivity.this, extendedSearchCollectionObj.getUIFIELDTYPE());

                fEditTextDF.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //  text =  workOrderListSearchCallBack.makeServiceCalls(extendedSearchCollectionObj.getDDCOLLECTIONNAME() ,extendedSearchCollectionObj.getDDFIELDNAME(), extendedSearchCollectionObj.getDDTABNAME());
                        // workOrderListSearchCallBack.getDialogList() ;

                        //  fEditText.setText(text);

                    }
                });

                fTableRow.addView(fLabelView);
                fTableRow.addView(fEditTextDF);
                fTableLayout.addView(fTableRow);

                break;

            case "DD":

                Button fButtonDD = (Button) CommonElements.getCreateButton(WorkOrderSearchActivity.this, extendedSearchCollectionObj.getUIFIELDTYPE());

                fButtonDD.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    }
                });

                fTableRow.addView(fLabelView);
                fTableRow.addView(fButtonDD);
                fTableLayout.addView(fTableRow);

                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Dialog

```
public void getDialogList(Boolean mFilterApplicable ) {
        if(mFilterApplicable == true){
            for (int i = 0; i < mDynamicDropDownList .size(); i++) {
                DynamicDropDown mDynamicDropDownObj = mDynamicDropDownList.get(i);
                mFieldValueDesc.add((CharSequence) (mDynamicDropDownObj.getFieldkeyvalue() + "" + mDynamicDropDownObj.getFieldkeyvalue()));
            }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < mCommonDropDownListCollectionList .size(); i++) {
            CommonDropDownCollection mCommonDropDownCollectionObj = mCommonDropDownListCollectionList.get(i);
            mFieldValueDesc.add((CharSequence) (mCommonDropDownCollectionObj.getCommonKeyValue() + "" + mCommonDropDownCollectionObj.getCommonDescvalue()));
        }
    }

    fDDlistarray = new CharSequence[mFieldValueDesc.size()];
    fDDlistarray = mFieldValueDesc.toArray(fDDlistarray);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(WorkOrderSearchActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Make your selection");


    builder.setItems(fDDlistarray, new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            fEditTextID.setText(fDDlistarray[which].toString());
        }

    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();


}
```

Comment: Can you add screenshots and describe what exactly is the problem, its unclear right now and probably that's the reason you are not getting any help.

Comment: I need 10 reputation to post images

Comment: Anyways the question is i have  Dynamically added rows in the table layout    and  then have added edit texts in the rows.  But on click of edit text a dialog box has to appear and then the text is set to editText  onClick of Dialog Box........But in this case the setText  is always done for the last row even if i click the first one

Comment: lalita, you need to assign each edit text a unique Id, as per your code fEditTextID will always contains reference for last added EditText in layout, hence no matter which EdiText you click to pop the dialog, text will end up setting in last EditText only.

Comment: Thanks Got it ....I assigned id for each row and fetched the child view using getChildAt().